# CKeditor And php echo

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to add CKeditor to this script. It works fine when I add openwysiwyg to it. but i just cant seem to get ckeditor to work. I added this to the head

```
 <head><script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> </head> 
and this to ---> echo "  <script>CKEDITOR.replace( \'HtmlEditor3\' );</script>
```

the body. i get this  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected on line 285`

```
<?php

   // *************************************** //

   //                CHIP                    //

   //                                        //

   // *************************************** //



   define('ADMIN_PASS', 'password');

   $upload_folder = "./images/";

   $max_size = 200000;

   $database = './news_db.php';

   $admin_password = isset($_COOKIE['admin_password']) ? $_COOKIE['admin_password'] : '';



   if (empty($admin_password))

   {

      if (isset($_POST['admin_password']))

      {

         $admin_password = md5($_POST['admin_password']);

          if ($admin_password == md5(ADMIN_PASS))

          {

             setcookie('admin_password', $admin_password);

          }

      }

   }



   (is_writable($database)) ? include($database): die ($database . ' is not writable or does not exist! Please read the manual for more details.');

   $action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

   $index = isset($_REQUEST['index']) ? $_REQUEST['index'] : -1;

   $is_admin = ($admin_password == md5(ADMIN_PASS));

   $is_modified = false;

   $count = sizeof($news);

   if ($action == 'logout')

   {

      setcookie('admin_password', '');

      unset($_COOKIE['admin_password'], $admin_password);

      header("Location: ".basename(__FILE__));

      exit;

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'save')

   {

      $text = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? trim($_POST['text']) : addslashes(trim($_POST['text']));

      $text = str_replace("\\'", "&#39;", $text);

      if ($index >= 0 && $index < $count)

      {

         $news[$index] = $text;

      }

      else

      {

         $news[$count] = $text;

         $count++;

      }

      $is_modified = true;

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'movedown')

   {

      if ($index > 0 && $index < $count)

      {

         $temp = $news[$index-1];

         $news[$index-1] = $news[$index];

         $news[$index] = $temp;

         $is_modified = true;

      }

      else

      {

         header('Location: '.basename(__FILE__));

         exit;

      }

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'moveup')

   {

      if ($index >= 0 && $index < ($count-1))

      {

         $temp = $news[$index+1];

         $news[$index+1] = $news[$index];

         $news[$index] = $temp;

         $is_modified = true;

      }

      else

      {

         header('Location: '.basename(__FILE__));

         exit;

      }

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'delete')

   {

      $count--;

      for ($i=$index; $i < $count; $i++)

      {

         $news[$i] = $news[$i+1];

      }

      $is_modified = true;

   }

   if ($is_modified && $is_admin)

   {

      $content = "<?php\r\n";

      for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)

      {

         $content .= '$news['.$i.'] = '."'".$news[$i]."';\r\n";

      }

      $content .= "?>";

      $content = str_replace('\"', '"', $content);

      $file = fopen($database, "wb");

      fputs($file, $content);

      fclose($file);

      header('Location: '.basename(__FILE__));

      exit;

   }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>News Writer</title>

<style type="text/css">

<!--

body

{

   font-size: 11px;

   font-family: Verdana;

   font-weight: normal;

   text-decoration: none;

   color: #212121;

}

-->

</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F7F6F3" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px">

<?php



   if ($action == 'admin')

   {

      echo "<center>\n";

      echo "Administrator login<br>\n";

      echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\">\n";

      echo "<input type=\"password\" name=\"admin_password\" size=\"20\" />\n";

      echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\" name=\"submit\" />\n";

      echo "</form>\n";

      echo "</center>\n";

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'image')

   {

      if ($is_admin)

      {

         echo "<center>\n";

         echo "Upload image<br>\n";

         echo "<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\" action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\">\n";

         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"upload\" />\n";

         echo "Image filename: <input type=\"file\" name=\"filename\"><br>\n";

         echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\">\n";

         echo "</form>\n";

         echo "<a href=\"" .basename(__FILE__). "\">Back to overview</a>\n";

         echo "</center>\n";

      }

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'imagelist')

   {

      if ($is_admin)

      {

         $ext_to_show = array("gif","jpg","jpeg","jpe","pjpeg");

         $files_to_show = array();

         if ($handle = opendir($upload_folder))

         {

            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))

            {

               if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file($upload_folder.$file))

               {

                  $ext = (pathinfo($upload_folder.$file));

                  if(in_array(strtolower($ext['extension']), $ext_to_show))

                  {

                     $files_to_show[] = $file;

                  }

               }

            }

            closedir($handle);

         }

         if(empty($files_to_show))

         {

            echo "No files to show.";

         }

         else

         {

            sort($files_to_show);

            foreach ($files_to_show as $file)

            {

               echo '<br><img src="'.$upload_folder.$file.'"alt="" align="middle" border="0" style="width:120px;height:90px;">'."\n";

               echo '<input type="text" size="30" value="'.$upload_folder.$file.'"><br>'."\n";

            }

         }

         echo "</body></html>";

         exit;

      }

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'upload')

   {

      echo "<center>\n";

      if (isset($_FILES['filename']))

      {

         $name  = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

         $type  = $_FILES['filename']['type'];

         $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

         $error = $_FILES['filename']['error'];

         $size  = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

         switch ($error)

         {

         case 0:

            if ($type == 'image/gif' || $type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/pjpeg')

            {

               if ($size <= $max_size)

               {

                  if (!file_exists($upload_folder. $name))

                  {

                     if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_folder. $name))

                     {

                        echo "Image succesfully uploaded!<br><br>\n";

                        echo "Filename:<br>". $upload_folder. $name. "<br>\n";

                     }

                     else

                     {

                        echo "Error: Upload failed, please verify the folder's permissions.\n";

                     }

                  }

                  else

                  {

                     echo "Error: The image already exists.\n";

                  }

               }

               else

               {

                  echo "Error: The image is too big.\n";

               }

            }

            else

            {

               echo "Error: Wrong file type, please only use jpg or gif images.\n";

            }

            break;

         case 1:

            echo "Error: The uploaded file exceeds the 'upload_max_filesize' directive.\n";

            break;

         case 2:

            echo "Error: The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.\n";

            break;

         case 3:

            echo "Error: The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.\n";

            break;

         case 4:

            echo "Error: No file was uploaded.\n";

            break;

         case 6:

            echo "Error: Missing a temporary folder.\n";

            break;

         case 7:

            echo "Error: Failed to write file to disk.\n";

            break;

         case 8:

            echo "Error: File upload stopped by extension.\n";

            break;

         }

      }

      else

      {

         echo "Error: No filename specified!<br>\n";

      }

      echo "<a href=\"" .basename(__FILE__). "\"><br><br>Back to overview</a>\n";

      echo "</center>\n";

      exit;

   }

   else

   if ($action == 'edit' || $action == 'new')

   {

      if ($is_admin)

      {

         $text = ($index >= 0) ? $news[$index] : '';

         echo "<form action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\" method=\"POST\">\n";

         echo "<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"4\" border=\"0\">\n";

         echo "<tr>\n";

         echo "<td>\n";

         echo "   <textarea id=\"HtmlEditor3\" style=\"width:100%;height:250\" name=\"text\">".$text."</textarea>\n";
         echo "  <script>CKEDITOR.replace( \'HtmlEditor3\' );</script>

         echo "</td>\n";

         echo "</tr>\n";

         echo "<tr>\n";

         echo "<td align=left>\n";

         echo "   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"save\" />\n";

         echo "   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"" . $index . "\" />\n";

         echo "   <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" />\n";

         echo "   <input type=\"button\" value=\"Back to overview\" onclick=\"window.location='" .basename(__FILE__) . "'\" />\n";

         echo "</td>\n";

         echo "</tr>\n";

         echo "</table>\n";

         echo "</form>\n";

      }

   }

   else

   {

      if ($is_admin)

      {

         echo "<a href=\"".basename(__FILE__)."?action=new\">Create new item</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

         echo "<a href=\"".basename(__FILE__)."?action=image\">Upload image</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

         echo "<a href=\"".basename(__FILE__)."?action=imagelist\" onClick=\"window.open('','img_list','scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=400, height=300')\" target=\"img_list\">Image List</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

         echo "<a href=\"".basename(__FILE__)."?action=logout\">Logout</a><br><br>\n";

      }

      if ($count > 0)

      {

         for ($i=$count-1; $i >= 0; $i--)

         {

            echo $news[$i];

            echo "<br>";

            echo "<br>\n";

            if ($is_admin)

            {

               echo "<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">\n";

               echo "<tr>\n";

               echo "<td>\n";

               echo "   <table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"4\" border=\"0\">\n";

               echo "   <tr>\n";

               echo "   <td>\n";

               echo "      <form action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\">\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"edit\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"" . $i . "\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\" />\n";

               echo "      </form>\n";

               echo "   </td>\n";

               echo "   <td>\n";

               echo "      <form action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\" onSubmit=\"return confirm('Delete item?')\">\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"delete\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"" . $i . "\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" />\n";

               echo "      </form>\n";

               echo "   </td>\n";

               echo "   </tr>\n";

               echo "   </table>\n";

               echo "</td>\n";

               echo "<td>\n";

               echo "   <table align=\"right\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"4\" border=\"0\">\n";

               echo "   <tr>\n";

               echo "   <td>\n";

               echo "      <form action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\">\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"moveup\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"" . $i . "\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Move Up\" />\n";

               echo "      </form>\n";

               echo "   </td>\n";

               echo "   <td>\n";

               echo "      <form action=\"" .basename(__FILE__) . "\">\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"movedown\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"index\" value=\"" . $i . "\" />\n";

               echo "      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Move Down\" />\n";

               echo "      </form>\n";

               echo "   </td>\n";

               echo "   </tr>\n";

               echo "   </table>\n";

               echo "</td>\n";

               echo "</tr>\n";

               echo "</table>\n";

            }

            echo "<hr>\n";

         }

      }

      else

      {

         echo "No news<br><br>";

      }

      if (!$is_admin)

      {

         echo "<a href=\"".basename(__FILE__)."?action=admin\">Admin login</a>";

      }

   }

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: missing `";` see the colour coding above, now go install a IDE that will point theses things out for you

Comment: Now I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in           Line 377

Comment: i have faith you can work it out.

Comment: Yes I Got IT Thank you!!!!!!!!!